# Splitting A String List Into Components

Tags: c++, string, split

I am trying to figure out a way to split the following string:

`"2.000000, ["Me", [13, 11], "You"], [12.000000, 15.000000]"`

such that I have a string vector with the following contents:

```
2.000000
["Me", [13, 11], "You"]
[12.000000, 15.000000]
```

I started with using `,`  as the regex, however this splits the sublists (`[...]`) inappropriately.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Straight-forward solution is to store balance of `[]` brackets on current prefix. `[` gives +1, `]` gives -1. Also don't update balance, ignore `[` and `]` inside `"strings"`

```cpp
int balance = 0;

// If balance is 0, you're outside your list:
//   [ ... ]
// ^ here    ^ or here
// If balance is >= 1, you're inside list:
// [ ... ]
//   ^^^
// If balance >= 2, you're inside sublist:
// [ ..., [ ..., [...] ], ... ]
//          ^ balance == 2
//                ^ balance == 3 and so on

// Ignore updating balance if [ and ] inside ""-s.
// E.g. balance won't increase
// ["["]
//   ^ here
// Also ignore commas here: [",", ","]
//                            ^    ^
bool inside_string = false;

std::string current_part;
std::vector<std::string> parts;

for (char c : s) {
  if (c == '"')
     inside_string ^= true;

  // Both comma and closing brace if balance is 1 can end current part.
  // Current part can't end inside ""-s.
  if (balance == 1 && (c == ',' || c == ']') && !inside_string) {
    parts.push_back(std::move(current_part));
    current_part = "";
    continue;
  }

  if (balance >= 1) {
    // No need to add space coming right after comma.
    if (current_part.empty() && c == ' ')
      continue;
    current_part += c;
  }

  if (!inside_string) {
    if (c == '[') {
      ++balance;
    } else if (c == ']') {
      --balance;
    }
  }
}
```

[Playground](http://cpp.sh/6rsej)

Answer (score 0):

Matching nested brackets with a regex is not a good approach. Instead, you can iterate over the string `input`, and simply keep track of whether you are currently inside a pair of brackets. If you are, and you encounter a `,` then split the string at that point, and otherwise ignore the `,`.

```
std::vector<std::string> result;

int prev = 0, in_brackets = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < std::ssize(input); ++i)
{
  if (input[i] == ',' and not in_brackets)
  {
    result.push_back(input.substr(prev, prev - i));
    prev = i + 1;
  }
  else if (input[i] == '[') in_brackets++;  // 1 more level of brackets 
  else if (input[i] == ']') in_brackets--;  // 1 less level of brackets
}

result.push_back(input.substr(prev));  // add the last chunk
```

---

`std::ssize` is a C++20 feature which returns the size of a range as a signed integer, which is much better to deal with it. If you don't have C++20, then use `std::size`, and cast the result to an `int` manually.